# ios automatic migration from images to assets catalog

Tags: ios, asset-catalog

I have really large number of images just in Images folder of my project (just @1x and @2x.png files). It's time to support @3x displays and I've decided to move to `assets catalog`. Are there any tools/scripts to automate this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try [iMigrate](https://github.com/Nikita2k/iMigrate), that I created recently. So it wasn't properly tested and you can use it own risk.

Answer (score 12):

Normally you already have an Asset Catalog because of your AppIcon. If not, choose **File:New:File ...** and then select **iOS Resource:Asset Catalog**.

The images you want to import should be named properly: image.png, image@2x.png. If you target both devices: image~iphone.png, image@2x~iphone.png, image~ipad.png, image@2x~ipad.png.

Then select Asset Catalog and press **+**. Choose the folder with the images you want to import.

[image: Import dialog]

Like that it´s very simple to import large numbers of pictures and you can have the same folder structure in your Asset Catalog, as you had before.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  "Import From Project" was exactly what I was looking for, and it imported every image from my Images folder into the asset catalog with a single click.  Saved me hours!

Answer (score -1):

You can make one of your own using **Apple Automator**. It is an automating script maker tool provided by Apple with the Mac OS. You can find plenty of online tutorials for it if you Google it up. Here's an example. [Click here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/58986/automator-for-mac-tutorial-and-examples)

Comment: Downvoter please leave a comment suggesting as to why the answer wqas downvoted. Helps improve my answer / expectation and also contributes to improve general quality of answers.

Comment: @anton Did you find this useful?